# Laravel/Angular - Auth::user() returns null

Tags: angular, laravel

I'm working with Angular 12 (frontend) and Laravel(backend). I'm sending the datas to the frontend with api. I want to get all users except one(authenticated) but it returns null. But the user seems to be logged in and also Auth::user() does not return null on other controllers. Where am I missing?

**It return null in this controller (PlayerController)**

```
public function getPlayers(){
    return response()->json(Auth::user(), 200);
}
```

**It not returns in this controller (UserController)**

```
public function user() {
    $user = User::where('id',Auth::id())->firstorfail();
    return response()->json($user,200);
}
```

**I am checking in UserController to show the authenticated profile on frontend and in Angular I make such a check.**

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
    });
    this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user', {headers}).subscribe(
      result => (this.user = result
      )
    );
```

**Do I need to check this kind of control in the PlayerController so that it doesn't return empty?**

Answer (score 0):

You should check access token in middleware

```
?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use App\Helpers\TokenUtils;
use App\Constant\System\CommonConst;

class VerifyAccessToken
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $token = '';

        if (!empty($request->header('Authorization'))) {
            $token = $request->header('Authorization');
        }

        if (empty($token)) {
            throw new AuthenticationException;
        }

        try {
            $data = self::processToken($token);
            if ($data['error'] == true) {
                throw new AuthenticationException;
            }
            $parsed = $data['token'];//TokenUtils::parse($token, Config::get('app.jwt_key'));
        } catch (\Throwable $e) {
            report($e);

            throw new AuthenticationException;
        }

        if ($parsed[CommonConst::EXP] < time()) {
            throw new AuthenticationException;
        }

        $request->merge([CommonConst::USER_INFO => $parsed]);
        $request->merge([CommonConst::USER_INFO_DATA => $parsed[CommonConst::DATA]]);

        return $next($request);
    }

    public function processToken($token)
    {
        $decoded = null;

        try {
            $decoded = TokenUtils::parse($token, Config::get('app.jwt_key'));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
//            return response(['error' => true, 'error_message' => 'Token invalid.', 'message' => 'TOKEN_INVALID'], 200);
        }
        if (!$decoded) {
            try {
                $decoded = TokenUtils::parse($token, Config::get('app.jwt_key_admin'));
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
//            return response(['error' => true, 'error_message' => 'Token invalid.', 'message' => 'TOKEN_INVALID'], 200);
            }
        }
        if ($decoded) {
            return ['token' => $decoded, 'error' => false];
        }

        return ['error' => true];
    }
}
```

TokenUtils.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

use Firebase\JWT\JWT;
use App\Constant\System\CommonConst;

class TokenUtils
{
    /**
     * Generate a new token information.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  array  $options
     * @return array
     *
     * @throws \Throwable
     */
    public static function make($data, $key, array $options = [])
    {
        $payload = [
            CommonConst::EXP => $options[CommonConst::EXP] ?? time() + CommonConst::EXP_DEFAULT,
            CommonConst::DATA => $data,
        ];

        return JWT::encode($payload, $key);
    }

    /**
     * Parse a given token to get information.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  array  $options
     * @return array
     *
     * @throws \Throwable
     */
    public static function parse($token, $key, array $options = [])
    {
        $parsed = JWT::decode($token, $key, ['HS256']);

        return [
            CommonConst::EXP => $parsed->exp,
            CommonConst::DATA => (array) $parsed->data,
        ];
    }
}
```

and set middleware in route, example:

```
Route::apiResource('/admin/user', AdminController::class)->parameters(['user' => 'id'])->middleware(['api', 'verify_access_token']);
```

I hope help your case